# Could not write metadata for '/website_1'./var/www/.metadata (Permission denied)

Tags: eclipse

When ever I open eclipse to work, I get the following message

> Could not write metadata for
>   '/website_1'./var/www/.metadata/.pluginsorg.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/website_1/.markers.snap
>   (Permission denied)

I click ok but it appears again. Actually it seems that somehow the application user of eclipse seems not to have permission on changing the project files of eclipse.

But I am not sure, because I am really new to ubuntu.
Can anyone help me please?
ty

Comment: Did you try running with sudo(root). Files under /var/www are protected by default but you can change the permissions define.

Comment: well I have opend the programm and I have selected /var/www/ as default workspase. You think I should change the path to /home and above?

Comment: Are you trying to run a web application? If yes which language are you using to run the app?

Comment: I am using php, and php seems to be installed succesfully. I even added chmod 777 var/www in order to view the website and It seems to work.

Comment: So I can add the first comment as answer to your question?

Comment: Well I changed the default workspace to be in home/myworkspaces and now I don't get the error anymore. So probably your suggestion gave me qlue, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try running your application as `root(sudo su)`.
- Change the permissions of `/var/www` directory (write) .
- Please keep all the user related files under `$HOME`.